# xcode debugger options

Tags: xcode, debugging

[image]

What are the three options we see in the debug console in Xcode? Just curious to know why there are three options? What purpose each option serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugger output is stuff printed by the debugger itself, and target output is what is printed by your application (printf, NSLog, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a read through of the [Xcode User's Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html) would do us all a little good tonight:

> The Console Pane
>
> The console pane displays program output and lets you enter commands
>   to the debugger tool. You specify the type of output the console
>   displays with the pop-up menu in the top-left corner of the console
>   pane:
>
> All Output displays target and debugger output.
>
> Debugger Output
>   displays debugger output only.
>
> Target Output displays [target](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) output
>   only.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why the documentation written by apple itself is somehow a bad source of information?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think the reason someone downvoted is because there is no explanation of the terms themselves - what you posted is just a wordier version of the dropdown.  It doesn't help to understand what "target output" means.

Comment: If they don't understand what a target is, then how have they been building with, and using, Xcode in the first place?  While it may not always be best to just post a link or a snippet of text, in this case, the concept is simple enough that it doesn't warrant a verbose post.  I'd rather not have to explain how a filter works.

Comment: Besides, all of this is explained in the Xcode User Guide, which is far more comprehensive than any post I, or anyone else here, could put out.

Comment: You can easily understand what the "Target" is in terms of building, without understanding just what "Target output" means.  For instance, it could mean compiler notes!  A better name would be something like "Application Output" to make it clear it's the running application output that is being selected to view.  In any case, while one COULD wade through a heft volume of information in the docs to find that possibly, a succinct and clear answer here on SO is overall more useful to more people than the docs will ever be.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, but again it's all subjective.  I saw a relatively simple subject, and found the relatively simple answer in the documentation that answered the original question.  If the information were spurious, false, or inflammatory, I could see how it warrants a downvote, but it's not.  It is the very definition of succinct (especially in comparison to what it came out of).  If they insist on nitpicking the small things, then they can just use Google.  "Xcode Target" is enough to pull up an entire article by Apple about targets.

Comment: I'll give you an unfiltered answer.  The first part of your answer was a bit too snarky, the second part just copied Apple docs that anyone could have looked up easily.  A good SO answer is something that doesn't just say "RTFM" and then give you a bit of the 'ol FM, it's a distillation that brings clear and direct meaning.  Basically, just look at your answer compared to the accepted answer.  Just that contrast alone could easily bring someone to downvote (and again, I did not do so).  Sorry to be so blunt but you seem really mystified by the downvote, when I think the cause is pretty clear.

Comment: Again, point taken, but that still does not address the fact that this question does not require a more detailed answer than a look through docs, or even just a one sentence blurb (see the accepted answer).  Yes, comparatively, this answer is crap, but it's the answer that is parallel to the quality of the post.  If I need to go diving around in the internals of Xcode to produce a multi-paragraph thesis for a 3 sentence question, then it defeats the purpose of the succinctness you outlined above.